# Count based on condition using query builder not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm experiencing some issues with the result set I'm getting from my Laravel query

**The Query**

```
     $collegecounts = DB::table('colleges as cs')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(college_id) as graduates'),'cs.id','cs.collegename',
            DB::raw('round(AVG(st.status_id),0) as average'),
            DB::raw("(CASE WHEN (st.status_id = 4) THEN count(st.college_id) END) as placements")

        )
        ->join('students as st', 'st.college_id', '=', 'cs.id')
        ->groupBy('st.college_id', 'cs.id', 'cs.collegename')
        ->get();
```

Expected results are similar to the table below: (Placements column on the table below is a status_id count)

[image]

SQL Table:

**The Student Table**

| Column |
| --- |
| id |
| Name |
| College_id |
| Status_id |

**The College Table**

| Column |
| --- |
| id |
| Name |
| location |

The status is found in the status table.  If I don't add the status_id in the groupby query, I get an error that requires me to add status_id to groupby.  Upon adding it to Groupby, then I get more columns, for each student, instead of the grouping by college.  I also tried using `having` instead of the `case condition` I get the same result

The error:

> SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "st.status_id" must
> appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE
> 1: ...ound(AVG(st.status_id),0) as average, (CASE WHEN (st.status_...
> ^

I can easily add st.status_id to the `group by`, however that doesn't get me the correct result

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'sum' for counting with condition. The query below as your expected result:

```
select c.name, count(s.id) as Graduates, SUM(s.status_id=4) AS Placements
from college as c join student as s on s.collegge_id = c.id
group by c.id
```