# SQL grouping with 3 data

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I think what I need isn't that complex but I've already spent days playing with SQL queries.

Here my basic table structure

```
id |  status  | date
1  |  active  | 2020-01-02
2  | complete | 2020-01-03
3  | complete | 2020-01-03
4  |  active  | 2020-01-03
```

I'm trying to achieve this result on my query, grouping the result by `date` then counting the following

```
total - based on total row count by date, 
active - based on active status by date, 
complete - based on complete status by date
```

this is my desired format below

```
[
    {
        total: 1,
        active: 1,
        completed: 0,
        date: "2020-01-02"
    },
    {
        total: 3,
        active: 1,
        completed: 2,
        date: "2020-01-03"
    }
]
```

This runs on Laravel and I'm trying to play with Eloquent as well as the Query builder
but no success

```
$leadReport = Lead::select(
    DB::raw('count(id) as `total`'),
    //DB::raw('count(CASE WHEN `status` = `active ) as `active`'),
    //DB::raw('count(CASE WHEN `status` = `complete`) as `completed`'),
    DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as date")
)->where('iso','au')->groupBy('date')->orderBy('date')->get();

return $leadReport;
```

Appreciate any help

**EDIT**
just want to thank you @Yazan for the recommended query by using `SUM`,
I manage to use it on laravel query builder like below

```
$leadSummary = Lead::select(
    DB::raw("Sum(CASE WHEN status = 'completed' AND json_unquote(json_extract(`lenders`, '$.current_status')) IN ('Settled', 'Funded') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS settled"),
    DB::raw("Sum(CASE WHEN status = 'completed' AND json_unquote(json_extract(`lenders`, '$.current_status')) NOT IN ('Settled', 'Funded') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS rejected"),
    DB::raw("Sum(CASE WHEN status = 'active'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS active ")
)->where('iso','au')->get();
```

Comment: What is your result now? Have you tried using raw SQL (either from laravel or your database client)? Have you tried dumping your sql to see any anomalies?

Comment: You're using backticks both for column names and values here. That means both e.g. `status` and `complete` are the names of columns where it should be `'complete'` in single quotes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count based on condition using query builder not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65466733/count-based-on-condition-using-query-builder-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `sum` instead of `count` like this

```
SELECT Count(id)                     AS total,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN status = 'active' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END)                      AS active,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN status = 'completed' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END)                      AS completed,
       Date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date
FROM   MYtable
GROUP  BY date
ORDER  BY date;
```